# How to check if some access_token of FB is valid in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

I know that there is [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem for Rails to work with Facebook. I need to make clear 2 things:

1. How to check if some access_token is valid in Rails using Koala (or something else)?
2. How to generate some real access token (using some settings of my app or my login/password) for testing through RSpec?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For #1 Use the Tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug if you don't want to code a test. Otherwise hit this API and verify the response.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?client_id={APP_ID}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

For #2, Koala has a good API for accessing Facebook Test Users, which I recommend for use in Rspec.

> We also support the test users API, allowing you to conjure up fake
>   users and command them to do your bidding using the Graph or REST API:

```
 @test_users = Koala::Facebook::TestUsers.new(:app_id => id, :secret => secret)
 user = @test_users.create(is_app_installed, desired_permissions)
 user_graph_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user["access_token"])
 # or, if you want to make a whole community:
 @test_users.create_network(network_size, is_app_installed, common_permissions)
```

You can also create Test User in the App Settings from Facebook, and view thier details from this API :

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}/accounts/test-users?%20access_token={APP_TOKEN}
```